# How to dynamically add chip with text from Edittext to Edittext by pressing spacebar?

Tags: android, kotlin

**How to dynamically add chip with text from Edittext to Edittext by pressing spacebar?**

Tried

```
val textWatcher = object : TextWatcher {
        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
            lastLength = s!!.length
        }

        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
            if (lastLength > s!!.length) return
            if (s[s.length - 1] == SPACE) {
                val chip = ChipDrawable.createFromResource(this@MissingActivity, R.xml.standalone_chip)

                chip.text = str
                chip.setBounds(0, 0, chip.intrinsicWidth, chip.intrinsicHeight)

                val span = ImageSpan(chip)
                val text = editText?.text!!
                text.setSpan(span, 0, text.length, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)


            } else {
                str = s.toString()
                Log.d("MyLog", "finishRow")
            }
        }

        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
        }
    }
    editText?.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher)
```

And this method works, but text after a space is added to the existing chip.

[Example(pic)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49rJS.png)

And also you can't hang a listener on any chip. I would be very grateful for your help

Comment: https://github.com/hootsuite/nachos